# fullCalendar listview and how to display properly on mobile?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Sorry for noob questions,
I am using fullcalendar plugin and have a small question,

to add the listview(listWeek,listDay..) which file do i have to edit?

Also, on mobile phone, when the screen is small the events in the calendar goes out of the box, any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: "which file do I edit". This suggests you have no idea how the calendar works...have you read the docs or created one yourself yet? You don't edit a file, you write some javascript in your web page and pass in the settings. The demo on the front page https://fullcalendar.io/ includes the listView, so if nothing else you can look at the source for this and see how it's done (trivially, is the answer). See also the documentation here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/ and here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/

Comment: As for the mobile view, calendars in anything other than agenda view are inherently unsuited to small and narrow screens. They rely on essentially a fixed view and dimensions in order to make everything lay out in the conventional way you'd expect. Otherwise it wouldn't look like a calendar any more and wouldn't be easy to understand. So there's not really a lot that can be done about that.  Look at the built-in calendar app on your phone - the events don't fit in the boxes there either, if they're longer than a few characters.